# Create PDF of A4 size paper with images of original sizes

Tags: ios, objective-c, pdf, uigraphicscontext

I am converting each PPT slide into images and creating a PDF from them. Images are created properly with their original sizes. Now to create PDF I am using below code.

```
    CGSize paperSize = CGSizeMake(595.2,841.8);

    NSString *strPath = [[documentsPaths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"slide%i.png", i]];
     NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath]];

    UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0,paperSize.width ,paperSize.height);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(rect, nil);
                [image drawInRect:rect];

UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

What it exactly does is, drawing image with paper size and not it's original size. I want to draw image with original size on A4 size paper. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: you passed paper size when image draw  check this line   [image drawInRect:rect] so pass original size when draw pdf

Comment: So it created PDF with size of image.

Comment: @kirtimali : you are right. Passing A4 size to rect worked. Thank you so much. Plus one. Posting my working code in answers.

Answer (score 1):

Kriti's suggestion worked for me. Below is working code:

```
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfFile, CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height), nil);

NSString *strPath = [[[appDelegate getDocumentDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"EPC"] stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"slide%i.png", i]];        

NSData *imgData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:strPath]];

image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imgData];
    rect = CGRectMake((paperSize.width - image.size.width)/2, (paperSize.height - image.size.height)/2 ,image.size.width ,image.size.height);

UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(CGRectMake(0, 0, kPaperSizeA4.width, kPaperSizeA4.height), nil);

[image drawInRect:rect];


UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```